# Using setInterval to post data periodically to DB

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

I want to post data from my website to my database every few seconds using the setInterval function. I don't get any error messages, the page just refreshes removing any entered data but no data is posted to the database

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <form onclick="startPost()" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <textarea name="field1" id="field1"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" id="post">
   </form>
 </div>
```

```
function startPost(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("field1").load("post.php");
    }, 4000)
}
});
```

post.php

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

$post1 = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['field1']);

$insert = "INSERT INTO DBtable (WebText) VALUES ($post1)";

$resultinsert = $connection->query($insert);


if(!$resultinsert){

  echo $connection->error;
}else{
  echo "<p> Text is posting </p>";
}

?>
```

I want the data to be posted to the DB every four seconds but the page just refreshes on hitting submit. The connection.php connects to the database

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Sounds like you may need tyo use AJAX rather than a php only solution.  What data are yuou trying to collect?  PHP is refreshing the page, but cant instruct the client side to submit data.  Yude need a client side language to do that.

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of concepts. Using `.load` on jQuery, you are trying to simulate a POST request (though, it really isn't and you really aren't sending anything to the server). On submit, you are performing a form submit, which involves a page reload, making the interval invalid. As a final side note, as mentioned already, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: I'm trying to send text entered into the textarea to a database every four seconds. The data collected is just text entered onto the website by the user.

Answer (score 0):

HTML form submissions have a default behavior to refresh at the end of the submit.

```
<form onclick="startPost(event)" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Pass the event to your function like above

```
function startPost(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setInterval(function(){
        $("field1").load("post.php");
    }, 4000)
}
});
```

Add preventDefault to stop this default behavior.  Different browsers sometimes react differently and sometimes it's necessary to also perform `event.stopPropagation()`  This prevents the event from triggering onclicks to its parent elements as well.  Not needed in your exact case.

EDIT:

In order to stop reload on submission exactly you would need to catch the event onsubmit as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="preventReload(event)" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

```
function preventReload(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

Comment: This answer is conceptually correct, though the `.load` will still not really perform a relevant post request, but just an empty one. You should address the problems entirely: resolving the timeout issue is a good starting point, but you should provide a solution about the missing post data as well.

Comment: It also occurs to me that the preventDefault should actually be attached to the submission itself, not the onclick.  Better yet, attach it to the form's onsubmit="" attribute

Comment: If I need to be entirely honest, The form here is unnecessary, it can just be removed.

Comment: while that is entirely true, the source of OPs confusion is the page reloading, which is entirely caused by the default behavior of the form submission.  This answers the question that others might have stumbling onto this question later.

Comment: It still won't post data, though. You should fix that as well :P